# OpenSSL x509 utility PEM to DER conversion fails with "PEM_read_bio:no start line"

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

Trying to convert .pem file to .der file using below command.

```
openssl x509 -in public_key.pem -out cert.der -outform DER
```

getting below error

```
unable to load certificate
31833:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSS
L098/OpenSSL098-52.30.1/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFIC
ATE
```

I have generated RSA private/public keys using below.

```sh
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
```

Comment: You have generated an RSA key pair, not a certificate. Each certificate contains a public key, and you can create a certificate using an RSA key...

Comment: @Robert Can you please guide,how to do this?

Comment: You probably need a certificate, as per the answer and dupe. But if you actually want a file with ONLY the publickey, which in practice is usable only with OpenSSL and some Java programs (those handling the key explicitly using `X509EncodedKeySpec`), do `openssl {rsa,pkey} -pubin -in public.pem -out public.der -outform der` or just do `openssl {rsa,pkey} -in private.pem -pubout -out public.der -outform der` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a RSA key pair. And you are trying to convert the public key into DER format.

`openssl x509` command requires public key inside the X.509 container.

Try this command to create the Private Key and Public Cert.

1. Create a self signed CA Cert:

   `openssl genrsa  -out CAkey.pem 2048`

   `openssl req -new -x509 -key CAkey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 1095`
2. Now create another cert which is signed by the CA created above

   `openssl genrsa  -out serverkey.pem 2048`

   `openssl req -new -key serverkey.pem -out server.csr`

   `openssl x509 -req -days 1000 -in server.csr -CA cacert.pem -CAkey CAkey.pem -out server.pem -set_serial 01`

Later convert the public cert in PEM to DER format.

```
openssl x509 -in server.pem -out server.der -outform DER
```

Comment: The certificate likely will *not* be well formed if the only thing you are doing is shown above.

Comment: @jww, I have edited the answer adding more relevance. I would like to understand your comment. Can you please elaborate why certificate may not be well formed?